# Pass Audio/Video stream to html page using PhoneGap on iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm working on RealTime Communication project on iOS. It has video call feature...

It is working good on native code (objective-c) but I'm trying to create a PhoneGap plugin, I dont know how would I pass the audio and video stream into HTML from Objective-C.

Appreciate your help!

Thanks in Advance,
Sri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Cordova does not support natively WebRTC ( I just experimented it some days ago.. ).

But you can actually use some plugins for Cordova like this [one](http://phonertc.io/).
Or you can use [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) which does support WebRTC and a good and simple exemple  [here](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/webrtc.html).

Hope that help you :)